# Check for monotonicity, convexity

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I have the following function:

$$ f(x) =\sin(x) - \sqrt{3} * \cos(x) $$ and $$ I = [-\pi , +\pi] $$

I should check this function for **monotonicity** and **convexity**. So I drawed the $\sin$ and $\cos$ on a paper to see how the curve goes between $-\pi$ and $+\pi$. but the whole function is a sum between $\sin$ and $\cos$, so how do I do that? My brain stops there. I surely can see where the sin or cos for itself is monotonic but don't know how to add them together, and the $\sqrt3$ gets me confused too.

$$ f'(x) = \cos(x) + \sqrt3 * \cos(x) \\
   f''(x) = -\sin(x) +\sqrt3 * \cos(x) $$

I then made first and 2nd derivative. But how will i go further? I know where the sin(x) is monotonic .. but I don't know where $\sin x + \cos x$ is. I'm really having a bad time combining and imagining these 2 together..

Or is there just a 100% mathematical approach without looking at the graphs?

Comment: you need to determine the sign of $f'$ and $f''$. To do that find when they become zero and then check the sign at other values of $x$. How does increasing decreasing co-relate with sign of $f'$. How does convexity correlate with sign of $f''$.

Comment: hm. so i looked at $f' $ at wolframalpha and i see the changing of the sign at the first root. so should i check for roots of f'? to determine at which x my f' goes from negative to positve which means my original function keeps rising, not falling?

i did that and now i have tan $ x = \frac{1}{\sqrt3} $ which is $ x = arctan..$ right?

Comment: It may be easier to first transform the function to the form $2\sin(x+?)$.

Comment: just by calculating roots of the first and second derivative, I get my points where something "happens". but I dont know if this is the principle or way of doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the following.

[image]

This is the graph of the function $f$ and its derivatives. So intervals of monotonicity and convexity of the function $f$ are those of constant signs of the first derivative and the second, respectively. To find them we should to solve the equalities $f’(x)=0$ and $f’’(x)=0$. For this purpose we use the standard approach.

$$a\sin x+b\cos x=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin (x+y)= \sqrt{a^2+b^2}(\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y).$$

From here we have $\cos y=a/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and  $\sin y=b/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. In our particular case, $\cos y=1/2$, $\sin y=-\sqrt 3/2$, so we may put $y=-\pi/3$. So we have $f(x)=2\sin (x-\pi/3)$.

Comment: I do understand that we set our derivative to zero. But I am not sure about the a sin x + b cos x. If I really need that? Because I will not remember all kind of formulas like this in the exam.

Comment: @DominiqueLüber I don’t remember these formulas too, but the solution of the equality $a\sin x+b\cos x=0$ should be simple. If $a\not=0$, then we have $\tan x=-b/a$, and the roots of this equation should separate the real line into open intervals of alternating constant signs of the function $a\sin x+b\cos x$.

Comment: i had something like tan x = .. to. but then my approach would be the arctan.. would that be not correct?

Comment: @DominiqueLüber The set of solutions of the equation $\tan x=-b/a$ should be $A=\{\arctan(-b/a)+\pi n:n\in\mathbb Z\}.$ So you should consider those of them which belong to the investigated interval $I$ for the function $f$ (in our case it is $[-\pi,\pi]$).